# Multiple Dropdown Value bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi I am trying to convert the `ul > li` as `select > option`, if I select the first option in the `dropdown` list, it should be viewed. I'm done with it, but when I am using it for two times in a single page am getting the error.

```js
$(".dropdown-menu").on('click', 'li a', function(){
  $(".btn:first-child").text($(this).text());
  $(".btn:first-child").val($(this).text());
});
```

```css
*{
  border-radius: 0 !important;
}
li{
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<li role="presentation" class="dropdown">
  <label>Quantity 
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle btn btn-default" id="drop5" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      Select 
      <span class="caret"></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="menu2" aria-labelledby="drop5"> 
      <li><a href="#">In Stock</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Out of Stock</a></li>
    </ul>
  </label>
</li>
<hr>
<li role="presentation" class="dropdown">
  <label>Quantity 
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle btn btn-default" id="drop5" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      Select 
      <span class="caret"></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="menu2" aria-labelledby="drop5"> 
      <li><a href="#">Price</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Dollar</a></li>
    </ul>
  </label>
</li>
```

Comment: you are getting which error ?

Comment: I've updated the code, please check it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to change the title of your dropdown you need to change only the text property not the value.

Moreover, your dropdown contains a title plus a glyphicon (i.e.: caret). You cannot change this element if you want to preserve the dropdown appearance.

That means:

- get the [closest](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) dropdown element corresponding to the current clicked element:
  $(this).closest('.dropdown')
- find inside this fragment the button:
  $(this).closest('.dropdown').[find](http://api.jquery.com/find/)('.btn')
- use [contents](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) in order to get all the dom elements (1. text node: the title; 2. span node: the span node; 3. text node: a new line)
- [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) this list by nodeType == textNode and text content not empty

The snippet:

```js
$(".dropdown-menu").on('click', 'li a', function(){
  $(this).closest('.dropdown').find('.btn').contents().filter(function(idx, ele) {
      return this.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE && this.textContent.trim().length != 0;
  }).get(0).textContent = this.textContent + ' ';
});
```

```css
*{
    border-radius: 0 !important;
}
li{
    list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>



<li role="presentation" class="dropdown">
    <label>Quantity
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle btn btn-default" id="drop5" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            Select
            <span class="caret"></span>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="menu2" aria-labelledby="drop5">
            <li><a href="#">In Stock</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Out of Stock</a></li>
        </ul>
    </label>
</li>
<hr>
<li role="presentation" class="dropdown">
    <label>Quantity
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle btn btn-default" id="drop55" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            Select
            <span class="caret"></span>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="menu22" aria-labelledby="drop55">
            <li><a href="#">Price</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Dollar</a></li>
        </ul>
    </label>
</li>
```

Answer (score 2):

When you set value and text, you are replacing all dom nodes matching that selector. Try like this instead,

```
$(".dropdown-menu").on('click', 'li a', function(e){
  $(".btn:first-child", $(e.target).closest('.dropdown')).text($(this).text());
  $(".btn:first-child", $(e.target).closest('.dropdown')).val($(this).text());
});
```